# comma after td entry html

Tags: html, css

I have a specific problem regarding some HTML code.  Within a relatedlist table, I want to insert commas immediately following the pulled entry, e.g., Austin, TX vs Austin TX.  What is the easiest way to accomplish this via html or CSS preferably (This is for WebEOC platform for those who are familiar). Here's a picture of the code that gives me the Austin TX result.  Thank you.   [Code without commas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbs3o.png)

Comment: Add code instead of picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<value-of select="concat(@city, ", ")" />
```

So instead concating a `blank space`, you concat a `,` and a `blank space`

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: similar problem here but different code.  I am trying to code a comma between "originating user"  and "originating_routingcode."  They placed a comma outside the field but it leaves a gap.  Is there a quick solution here as well?   <td class="NameColumn">
<eocfield name="originating_user" disableclick="true"/>,
<eocfield name="originating_routingcode" disableclick="true"/>
</td>

Comment: You should create a new question, and you should do following this advices if you don't want it closed too. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask